# How can I play Halo 4's Spartan Ops?

Tags: halo-4

I have this problem in *Halo 4's* Spartan Ops. Every time I want to play season 1 and the other seasons it has a warning sign saying "content missing on all of the mission selections" and down the bottom of the screen it says either "loading 0%" or "one or more players do not have these maps" or something like that. If anyone knows why or how to fix this problem please tell me, I really want to play Spartan Ops. All I can play is forge and war games

#### PS

If it does get fixed can you tell me how to start playing Spartan Ops offline or without gold? Everyone says you can play it offline but for me it keeps saying requires gold so can you tell me how to play it offline and how to start it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need Xbox Live Gold in order to play Spartan Ops. I can't find the original link, but I saw a lot of forum posts from about a year ago that are angry about this. I think this is because it is an extension of multiplayer, which also needs Gold.

If you do not have an Xbox Live Gold account now, that could explain the error messages you're getting, since I believe that while some of the content is on the disc, it also needs to download some as well.

If you do have Xbox Live Gold, have you downloaded [Spartan Ops Episodes 6-10](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Halo-4-Spartan-Ops-Season-1-Episodes-6-10/5815fe85-ae61-440d-9499-6c7c05f26756?cid=SLink)? I'm not sure if that would get rid of the errors or not, but it would be worth a try.

Comment: actually I do have gold and I have downloaded it three times and it doesn't work maybe its got something to do with the loading 0% thing or just the content missing I might download it again

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware only episodes 1-5 are available to offline players as they are already on disc. You need to insert and download the second disc so that the files are recognisable and quicker to install. Then, you have to install the disc onto the main Xbox Console. This will allow you access to things like Theatre mode and stuff now.

Unfortunately you need (as already stated) Xbox Live Gold Membership to download episode 6-10. As for the other seasons... they aren't out yet. And in relation to the whole 'Halo: 5' not actually going to be 'Halo: 5' well no one is really sure if Season 2 will come out for this game or for Halo 4. It's extremely odd, irritating and secretive in the way that 343 Industries are running the program. Good Luck thought, hope this help more or less...

Answer (score -1):

you can not play any of the spartan ops without xbox gold, with or without disc. I know this from personal experience.